# Downloading Jupyter Notebook as HTML (pandoc)

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandoc

I'm trying to download one of my Jupyter notebooks as HTML. I have tried "File" --> "Download as" --> "HTML (.html)" but I get an error message saying:

```
"Could not import nbconvert: No module named pandoc".
```

I have installed pandoc, through Anaconda Navigator (conversion to HTML still didn't work), downloaded it from their website (didn't work either). I manage to download it as an .ipynb file, however. I have also tried this in my command line:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
```

I get an error message saying:

```
ImportError: No module named pandoc
```

However, I HAVE installed pandoc, I've tried uninstalling it and downloading it again, but still, it doesn't work. Could someone help me resolve this?

Comment: the module is called pypandoc and not pandoc... have you tried upgrading jupyter to the most recent version?

Comment: @GregorSturm I have pypandoc installed as well, and I have upgraded jupyter to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The library that is doing the conversion under the hood is called `nbconvert`.

Could you provide some version information? E.g., what version of nbconvert are you using?

To do this, go to your terminal and run the command

`jupyter nbconvert --version`

There is some potential confusion around the name here too. I'm thinking that this is with reference to the `nbconvert` internal module named [`pandoc`](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/utils/pandoc.py) which interfaces with the library called [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/).

No matter what, `nbconvert` shouldn't require pandoc (either the module or the library) for exporting to HTML.

Feel free to leave an issue on https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues!

Edit (followup):

That means your version of nbformat needs to be upgraded, use the same command to upgrade nbformat, and you should be good to go!

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version of nbconvert, but now I get a different error: TypeError: validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'relax_add_props'